# Using strcmp to compare two elements in an array of structures returns incorrect value

Tags: c

I am attempting to use `strcmp` to compare to strings that are stored in an array of structures called index. This index contains a string called webpage and an int called rank. The idea is to compare the two indexes and create a third index that contains the webpages that are the same between the first two indexes and the sum of their respective ranks.

The problem is that when I use the for loop to find the number of similar pages between the indexes it always returns 7. It should only return 4. Am I incorrectly using this function?

int thesame = 0;

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if(strcmp(hotels[i].webpage,seattle[i].webpage) == 0) {
             thesame++;
         }
    }
}
printf("%d\n", thesame);

return 0;
```

I also understand that I have a lot of hardcoded values for the lengths and this is not good coding practice. I plan to get the program working before I change this.

Comment: I made changes suggested by Kirlenko and now the code looks like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7fdcd8c78c5e3db9d6bc I am getting a zero for the output now.

Comment: I find that adding printfs in the loop is useful to debug these. Something like if(strcmp(...) == 0) {...}else{printf("Wanted %s, got %s\n", hotels[i].webpage, seattle[j].webpage);} Maybe this will help you see why your strcmp results are not what you expect

Answer (score 7):

```
if (strcmp (hotels[i].webpage, seattle[i].webpage) == 0)
```

You are using the index `i` twice. I guess you want rather something like:

```
if (strcmp (hotels[i].webpage, seattle[j].webpage) == 0)
---------------------------------------^----------------
```

Comment: You're right. I made the change and I am only getting a zero now. The complete code is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7fdcd8c78c5e3db9d6bc